# VeraCrypt Command line volume switch (/v) error (Solved, see update at end)

Tags: veracrypt

Many visits but this is my first posting to Stack overflow - any help would be much appreciated!

I am writing a batch file to mount a VeraCrypt volume & cannot get the volume to mount.

Installed VeraCrypt vers 1.26.7 64 bit release date 10/1/23 on:

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 11 Pro    Version 10.0.22631 Build 22631
```

Created a 15GB volume (regular, not hidden) at "G:\Doug\Data\Data15n". Mounted.
Copied data to the volume.
Closed. Can open and close easily with the VC GUI.

BAT program:
blah, blah, blah all good, then:

```
    start "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz /p mypassword /q
    echo.
    echo Z Drive mounted, waiting 5 seconds...

Doesn't work. 


Opened cmd & tried:
    start "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz /p mypassword /q
response: Invalid switch - "/v". Next, eliminate the /q switch:
    start "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz /p mypassword 
response: Invalid switch - "/v". Next, eliminate the /p and /q switches:
    start "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\VeraCrypt.exe" /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz 
response: Invalid switch - "/v".
Then (still in DOS shell):
    cd "C:\Program Files\VeraCrypt\"
    VeraCrypt.exe /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz /p mypassword /q
response - pop-up window from VeraCrypt "Error while parsing command line"
    VeraCrypt.exe /v "G:\Doug\Data\Data15n" /lz /p mypassword /q
response - pop-up window from VeraCrypt "Error while parsing command line"
    start VeraCrypt.exe /v G:\Doug\Data\Data15n /lz /p mypassword /q
response - pop-up window from VeraCrypt "Error while parsing command line"
```

All the above running as admin but cmd shell NOT elevated. Tried running the cmd shell as admin (elevated), same responses.

What am I doing wrong? It seems that VC doesn't like my /v switch (and I did try /volume too) but I can't figure out why. I have used a very similar batch file on W8.1 with no problems.
veracrypt /? still says the /v switch is available.
I'm stumped!

3 Screenshots - https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EXTw5MvcURHdbOEzhCaEcmRB4YoxipDf?usp=sharing

Update - Adrian Kentleton solved my problem in the VeraCrypt forums. (here https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/6086453f57/ ) The solution was to change the drive letter switch from

```
/lz to 
/l z adding a space.
```